# What's the best choice for create a new primary key in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

imagine you have a N-N relationship with three tables created. By example, image you have a table for `CUSTOMER(id_customer, name)`, the car table `CAR(id_car, model, num_doors, ...)` (id_customer and id_car are the primary keys for their respective tables).
Now you create the table PURCHASE to relate CUSTOMER with CARS and create the FOREIGN KEYS...  The question is what is the best choice?

```
1.PURCHASE(id_customer, id_car, date_purchase) -> Primary keys are (id_customer, id_car). Foreign keys are (id_customer->CUSTOMER.id_customer and id_car->CAR.id_car).
2.PURCHASE(id, id_customer, id_car, date_purchase) -> Primary keys are (id), Foreign keys are (id_customer->CUSTOMER.id_customer and id_car->CAR.id_car).
```

My question is what is the best option, 1 or 2, taking into account efficiency and optimization in database.

Comment: From a use case standpoint it is possible a user could buy a car, sell it and then buy it again later.  So 1 seems like it could, on edge cases, cause problems.

Comment: The meaning of the question is not the concepts of buy a car. That's the example. The meaning of the question is what is better, te create a single primary key for the middle relatinship table or use the two foreing keys as a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

For a Many-to-Many mapping, do it this way.

```
CREATE TABLE XtoY (
    # No surrogate id for this table
    x_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to one table
    y_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   -- For JOINing to the other table
    # Include other fields specific to the 'relation'
    PRIMARY KEY(x_id, y_id),            -- When starting with X
    INDEX      (y_id, x_id)             -- When starting with Y
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Notes:

- Lack of an AUTO_INCREMENT id for this table -- The PK given is the 'natural' PK; there is no good reason for a surrogate.
- "MEDIUMINT" -- This is a reminder that all INTs should be made as small as is safe (smaller ⇒ faster). Of course the declaration here must match the definition in the table being linked to.
- "UNSIGNED" -- Nearly all INTs may as well be declared non-negative
- "NOT NULL" -- Well, that's true, isn't it?
- "InnoDB" -- More effecient than MyISAM because of the way the PRIMARY KEY is clustered with the data in InnoDB.
- "INDEX(y_id, x_id)" -- The PRIMARY KEY makes it efficient to go one direction; the makes the other direction efficient. No need to say UNIQUE; that would be extra effort on INSERTs.
- In the secondary index, saying justINDEX(y_id) would work because it would implicit include x_id. But I would rather make it more obvious that I am hoping for a 'covering' index.

See [Cookbook on building indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: I think you didn't understant the meaning of my question. I'm expert in create tables, my question is related with efficiency and optimization, is not a question about syntax or database understanding. Please, read it carefully before answer me. Thanks!

Comment: The two indexes I recommend gives you the best performance.  Adding `FOREIGN KEYs` (anywhere) slows things down.

Comment: Hi Rick, ok, I undersant it, but how about the next solution? In the solution you gave me, add a ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO, INDEX for y_id, x_id) and primary key the ID I just added. Then, you can reference this index in other tables instead require to create 2 index for reference it in additional tables.

Comment: Another table can reference this one via, or example, just `x_id`.  Maybe I don't 'understant'; please show us the reference that may be in trouble.

Comment: It's a thing litle hard to explian what I mean. But don't worry, if you say that's it better two primary keys as foreign keys too, don't worry, I'll apply you advice.

Comment: You cannot have "two primary keys".  Perhaps you meant "composite primary key"?